# Can . (period) be part of the path part of an URL?

Tags: url, rfc

Is the following URL valid?

http://www.example.com/module.php/lib/lib.php

According to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738 section the hpath element of an URL can not contain a '.' (period). There is in the above case a '.' after "module" which is not allowed according to RFC1738.

Am I reading the RFC wrong or is this RFC succeed by another RFC? Some other RFC's allows '.' in URLs (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I don't see where RFC1738 disallows periods (.) in URLs. Here are some excerpts from there:

```
hpath          = hsegment *[ "/" hsegment ]
hsegment       = *[ uchar | ";" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" ]
uchar          = unreserved | escape
unreserved     = alpha | digit | safe | extra
safe           = "$" | "-" | "_" | "." | "+"
```

So the answer to your question is: Yes, `http://www.example.com/module.php/lib/lib.php` is a valid URL.

Answer (score 18):

As others have noted, periods are allowed in URLs, but be careful. If a single or double period is used in part of a URL's path, the browser will treat it as a change in the path, and you may not get the behavior you want.

For example:

- `www.example.com/foo/./` redirects to `www.example.com/foo/`
- `www.example.com/foo/../` redirects to `www.example.com/`

Whereas the following will **not** redirect:

- `www.example.com/foo/bar.biz/`
- `www.example.com/foo/..biz/`
- `www.example.com/foo/biz../`

Comment: Can you give an example of a browser which makes this interpretation and does this kind of automatic rewrite? I am aware that certain web _servers_ will respond to HTTP requests with these redirects, but not of browsers which would rewrite these URLs themselves.

Comment: Load up chrome, open the network tab in dev tools, and navigate to `http://www.example.com/foo/../`. If you look in the network tab, you'll notice that the request was actually made to `http://www.example.com/`, without any server redirection.

Answer (score 11):

Periods are allowed. See section "2.3 Unreserved Characters" in this document:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

"Characters that are allowed in a URI but do not have a reserved purpose are called unreserved. These include uppercase and lowercase letters, decimal digits, hyphen, period, underscore, and tilde".

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with a period in a url.  If you look at the makeup in the grammar in the link you provided a period is mentioned via the '`safe`' group, which is included via `uchar` a

Ignore my answer, Adams is better