# Javascript/jQuery: determine given URL's domain: 'youtube.com' or 'vimeo.com'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, url

I need to process URLs with JS and find out if they belong to youtube.com, vimeo.com or none of them. How do I do that?

I found this question [How to get Domain name from URL using jquery..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815559/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url-using-jquery), but it keeps 'http://www.' part if it's included in the URL.

**EDIT:** People suggesting the `indexOf` solution: what if there's a `youtube.com` inside the URL path? Is this even possible? As in `www.example.com/?article=why_youtube.com_is_the_best`? This question [Can . (period) be part of the path part of an URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555553/can-period-be-part-of-the-path-part-of-an-url) seems to indicate that this is a valid URL.

Comment: Why not just parse that part out?

Comment: replace http://www.  with a blank !

Comment: Whats wrong with [indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) You can just check `if(url.indexOf('youtube.com')){_youtube here_}elseif(url.indexOf('vimeon.com')){_vimeo there_}else{_none of them_}` ?

Comment: Check my answer, it looks for host, not indexOf :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var a = 'http://www.youtube.com/somevideo/vimeo';
var b = 'http://vimeo.com/somevideo/youtube';

var test = checkUrl(b);
console.log(test); //prints Vimeo


function checkUrl(test_url) {
    var testLoc = document.createElement('a');
        testLoc.href = test_url.toLowerCase();
    url = testLoc.hostname;
    var what;
    if (url.indexOf('youtube.com') !== -1) {
        what='Youtube';
    }else if (url.indexOf('vimeo.com') !== -1) {
        what='Vimeo';
    }else{
        what='None';
    }
    return what;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9xxxu/2/)
    ​

Answer (score 0):

```
url = url.toLowerCase();

if (url.indexOf('youtube.com') > -1 || url.indexOf('vimeo.com') > -1) .....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(domain_name.indexOf("youtube.com") != -1 || domain_name.indexOf("vimeo.com") != -1){
        //...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'http://www.youtube.com/myurl/thevideo/';
var host = $('<a>click</a>').attr('href',url)[0].host;

if(host === 'www.youtube.com'){

}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to remove `www`, use this

```
var host = $('<a>click</a>').attr('href',url)[0].host.replace('www.','');
```

Comment: This still includes the `www` part.

Comment: you can remove it , if you want. Updated

Comment: But now it won't work if there's no `www`. So perhaps some `www` detection code needs to be implemented? This doesn't seem very efficient, although I might be wrong.